# Bloquear un rango de ips desde la base de datos php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ip

Muchas gracias por tu tiempo de estar en este tema.

Tengo un rango de ip muchas alrededor de 10mil ips y quiero que si la ip del visitor cumple con uno de los rangos que haga algo con un condicional, pero no se como obtener la ip desde la base de datos no he encontrado la forma que trabaje bien, si el rango o la ip esta de primer lugar funciona bien pero si esta en las ultimas filas o en el medio de las filas no trabaja no lee correctamente es obvio no creo que pueda buscar entre todas las ip sin saber lo que busca.

Estas son las consultas que he utilizado entre otras pero estas son las que me parecen mas logicas

```
$whitelist = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT user_ip FROM {$wpdb->prefix}lcl_users_ip WHERE 1"));

$whitelist = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}lcl_users_ip WHERE user_ip"));
```

Esta es la funcion que estoy usando

```
// split each part of the IP address and set it to an array
$validated1 = explode(".", $whitelist[0]->agent_ip);
$validated2 = explode(".", $clickip);

// check array index to avoid undefined index errors
if(count($validated1) >= 3 && count($validated2) == 4) {

        // check that each value of the array is identical with our whitelisted IP,
        // except from the last part which doesn't matter
        if($validated1[0] == $validated2[0] && $validated1[1] == $validated2[1] && $validated1[2] == $validated2[2]) {
                return true;
        }

}
```

Como podria obtener correctamente los resultados de la base de datos? para que pueda leer los rangos de ip sin importar si tengo 100mil resultados en la base de datos que pueda leer bien todo o sin importar en que fila esten por que la funcion trabaja bien pienso que solo es la forma en que estoy obteniendo el resultado

Comment: Bienvenido Danel! No entiendo bien tus consultas: en esta: `$whitelist = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}lcl_users_ip WHERE user_ip"));` sólo te hace falta la comparación... `$whitelist = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}lcl_users_ip WHERE user_ip=[aquí va la ip que obtuviste del usuario que se intenta loguear]"));`, tu otra consulta no la entiendo: por qué `WHERE 1`?

Comment: Puse 1 por que ha si me da todas las ip la coji de la base de datos la consulta y tambien intente ese where con la ip pero no me funciona por que la ip no existe en la base de datos solo existira el rango osea los primeros numeros de la ip que es lo que necesito verificar si existe en la base de datos pero no se como hacerlo